# How to override _setupDecimals() function in OpenZeppelin

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

How can override Opezeppelin default decimal point of 18. The documentation says the _setupDecimals() should be called from a constructor; what am I doing wrong.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20 {

    uint8 _decimals;

    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") {

         _decimals = 3;

         function _setupDecimals(uint8 decimals_) internal {
            _decimals = decimals_;
         }

        _mint(msg.sender, 5000 * 10 ** decimals());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_setupDecimals()` was available in the OpenZeppelin version 3 ([docs](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc20#ERC20-_setupDecimals-uint8-), [GitHub](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.4.2/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L287)).

Your `import` statement imports the latest version of the OpenZeppelin library, which is currently v4. This one implements the `decimals()` function ([docs](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc20#ERC20-decimals--), [GitHub](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.7.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L87)) that you can override.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 5000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }

    function decimals() override public view returns (uint8) {
        return 8;
    }
}
```